# Site redirects differently on mobile vs on computer

Tags: force.com-sites, mobile, redirect

I have a support page that is hosted on a force.com site. http://openstax.force.com/support?l=en_US&c=Products%3ACollege

When I access this site on my computer it works fine. When I access it on mobile it initially goes to the correct URL, but then it redirects to the below URL.

http://openstax.force.com/support/pkb_mobile#/pkb_mobile

What is causing this? How do I prevent this from happening?

Comment: Check code in your active homepage, it might have some logic to redirect to specific URL based on desktop or mobile. OOTB functionality is very unlikely.

Comment: I forgot to mention that this was working perfectly fine a few months ago. We just noticed that it wasn't working correctly today, but we don't think we made any changes since then that would impact this.

Answer (score 0):

All of this comes from the PKB files. I discovered that the home page was referencing a template visualforce page which was referencing a visualforce component. In the component I commented out the line below, and then everything worked fine.

```
//mobilePage = ("{!$Page.pkb_mobile}").replace('{!$Site.Prefix}/','');
```